# GenyMotion and VirtualBox 4.3.30 Yosemite

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I'm getting this message using Genymotion -

> Genymotion, “Unable to load VirtualBox engine.”

I updated VirtualBox 4.3.28 to VirtualBox 4.3.30 this morning and seems to be causing this. I reinstalled both, from scratch, swapping what I installed first each time. I restarted VirtualBox from terminal - No luck!  I have rolled back to VirtualBox 4.3.28 and all seems fine now, but was just wondering of others were having this issue and if they're was a workaround (other than not updating to VirtualBox 4.3.30).

## **EDIT (05/08/15)**

I have now updated the following and all works fine with VirtualBox 5.0:

- Android Studio Genymotion plugin to version 1.0.5
- Updated Genymotion to 2.5.2
- Updated to VirtualBox 5.0

further information can be found here (30th July 2015 entry): https://www.genymotion.com/#!/release-notes

Comment: Worth asking on virtualbox forum.

Comment: Cheers, I will do - I have the same problem with VirtualBox 5.0 as well, so maybe Genymotion will release a patch update if this isn't a localised problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are not alone ~~~~~   I have rolled back to VirtualBox 4.3.12

Answer (score 0):

Try use older version VirtualBox like 4.3.12

Link:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3_pre24